# Append two lists for TikZ foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, comma-separated-list

How can I make a TikZ `foreach` loop iterate over two lists consecutively? I had hoped that in my code below, the expression `\firstlist,\secondlist` would evaluate to `2,3,5,7,1,4,6`, but it doesn't work. I have tried mild variants, like `{\firstlist,\secondlist}` and `\firstlist\secondlist`, without success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\firstlist{2,3,5,7}
\def\secondlist{1,4,6}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach\x in \firstlist,\secondlist
  \node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (\x,0) {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that this can be done.  The foreach loop expects either a single macro or a comma-delimited list.  So either it just sees the `\firstlist` or it sees a two-element list `{\firstlist,\secondlist}`.  You could do a double loop: `\foreach \list in {\firstlist,\secondlist} \expandafter\let\expandafter\list\list \foreach \x in \list ...` but that's not all that pretty!  I think that creating an amalgam out of the two lists before the `\foreach` would be best.

Comment: The amalgam can be defined via `\edef\amalgamlist{\firstlist,\secondlist}` then `\foreach \x in \amalgamlist ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `\newforeach`:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{loops}[2013/05/01]
\begin{document}

\def\firstlist{1,3,...,9}
\def\secondlist{2,4,...,10}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \newforeach[expand list] \x in {\firstlist,\secondlist}
  \node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (\x,0) {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```